# "focus lies" vs "focus lays"

Tags: grammar, phrases

Are both "focus lies" and "focus lays" grammatically correct? Do they mean the same?

Examples

> Our focus lays on the electronic and mechanic sectors.

> Our focus lies in renewable energy sources.

EDIT: [Help using "lie" and "lay" correctly](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209243/help-using-lie-and-lay-correctly) says

> To Lay – to put or place something. To Lie – to rest or recline.

Is focus put there or is it resting there? I don't know. At the moment Google shows some 573 mil results for "focus lies on" and 72 mil results for "focus lays on" so both forms are used widely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Help using "lie" and "lay" correctly](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209243/help-using-lie-and-lay-correctly)

Comment: Sorry, not really. I have updated my question.

Comment: _Our focus lays on_ means that the _focus_ is placing something there, which is not what you want to say, I assume!

Comment: Picture this: Either our focus is sitting there, or *We lay* our focus there.

Comment: Why use either one? A simple _is_ will do it. The important description is of where, not who's involved as agent.

Comment: The version with *lay* seems to run afoul of the intransitive/transitive distinction that bedevils so many with this pair of verbs, unless we can somehow parse it with a phrasal verb (as in "That was *laid on* with a trowel"). I would suggest that you promote the word *focus* to the role of verb: "We focus [our efforts / our work] on . . . ." By favoring flesh-and-blood subjects ("We"), and active verbs that have semantic content (not just syntactic function), we can often procure a more vigorous, clear, and readable style.

Comment: "Lies" is fine. "Lays" is wrong (as is "dramatically").

Comment: @BrianDonovan you have probably guessed that I am not a native speaker but your advice feels universal. Where could I learn more about writing with a "more vigorous, clear, and readable style"? thanks

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek: textbooks on this by [Joseph M. Williams](https://www.amazon.com/Joseph-M-Williams/e/B001H6MZ40) are useful but unfortunately subject to textbook-style pricing (and endless new editions to cut out the used-book market). Titles are variations on *Style: Lessons in Clarity and Grace.* Speaking of native speakers, the principle does cut across languages, but one that is just inherently brilliant at making verbs carry most of the meaning is Ojibwe, in which even the days of the week and the colors of the rainbow are expressed as verbs (as in *be* Tuesday or *be* red).

Comment: Those aren't the numbers of Google hits I get. A lot of the early hits are of the form "Is 'focus lays on' correct? and there are other false positives. But _lay [on]_ is almost always transitive. You lay X on Y. X doesn't lay on Y (unless X is a hen and Y a nest).

Comment: Can 72 million writers be wrong? No, I'm certain that the internet would not harbor incorrect usage.

Comment: The issue is not "Is the focus put there or is it resting there?" Rather, it is "Is the focus putting something there or is it resting there? The subject of "lays" is the agent that puts something into some place, not the thing that gets put there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a lie-lay conundrum. Transitive vs. intransitive.

Your first example is grammatically incorrect and should read:

> Our focus lies on the electronic and mechanic sectors.

Your second example is correct.

A transitive verb takes a direct object.

In "I like fruits" and "she makes cakes," the verbs "like" and "makes" are transitive.

An intransitive verb does not take a direct object.

In "she spoke softly" and "I run fast," the verbs "spoke" and "run" are intransitive.

**Lay** is transitive, takes an object. For example: "She *laid* the notebook on the table."

[lay](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/lay)

> to place (someone or something) down gently in a flat position

Note the tenses of *lay*: “lay, laid, laid” (to place or put down)

**Lie** is intransitive, does not take an object.  For example:  "My dog *lies* here."  "She *lay* unconscious on the bed."  The past tense of *lie* is *lay*.

[lie](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/lie1_1?q=lie)

> to be located in a particular place

Tenses of *lie*: “lie, lay, lain” (to recline or remain)

There are many verbs which are both transitive and intransitive.

For example:  "She has been singing all day."  "She has been singing the same song all day."

Comment: I think your answer and additional commentary are quite useful and explain your reasoning quite well. However, your discussion of "lie" and its tenses and definition don't exactly fit/apply to the example sentence: "Our focus lies on the electronic and mechanic sectors." I don't think "our focus" is in a flat position on a surface. Perhaps a different definition would fit better for the OPs question?

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva, fair enough! I failed to notice it.

Answer (score 3):

I've spent my life listening to "'Lie', not 'Lay'" and its ever so pleasant variations. Here it is clearly "focus 'lies' not 'lays'".

I delight in the distinction of Transitive over Intransitive but the problem here is also usage and consistency.

The meaning of "Our focus *lies* on the electronic and mechanic sectors." is that the focus is already there, is there currently. This is distinct from the mistaken usage; "Our focus lays there." which would mean our focus is in action, on the way to being there. Painful and quite incorrect for this sentence. *Laying* describes an action, not a static condition.

More important (what I forgot) is the fact that the expression being used has no physical reality. Whether the focus lays or lies is not the point of the sentence. *Focus* here means *The emphasis* of our various sectors. The physical nature of transitive or intransitive matters only by way of habit. In this case the habit of our *Usage* of the terms. According to the numbers 'Lies" is still in the lead.

Such common usage would account for your millions being 573 to 72 give or take. My Mother will get back to each of those poor 72 mil.