# Which sentence is grammatically correct lay or laid in this situation?

Tags: grammar, etymology, intransitive-verbs, lie-lay-lain-laid

She **lay** on the beach while her son splashed at the water's edge.

or

She **laid** on the beach while her son splashed at the water's edge.

[Grammarly](http://www.grammarly.com) is indicating that both are correct, but [Word Power](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0143424688) says that the first is correct.

Comment: There is a related question with a good answer at [Help using lay and lie](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209243/help-using-lie-and-lay-correctly).

Comment: @Jason Bassford Lied?

Comment: @Jason Bassford It's only *lied* in the other sense of the word: to fib!

Comment: I lie on the beach everyday. Yesterday, I lay on the beach for two hours. Recently, I have lain on the beach for hours on end. In short: **lie, lay, lain**.

Comment: I lay the table every night; Last night I laid the table. Recently, I have laid the table more than my sisters. In short: **lay, laid, laid**. [to set something down]

Comment: More help: [What is the difference between “lay” and “lie”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105/what-is-the-difference-between-lay-and-lie).

Comment: Depending on context (which has not been provided), they are both grammatical. If she reclined on the beach in the past, then she *lay* on the beach. As mentioned in a comment under the current single answer, if *she* is a chicken, then it's quite correct to say that she "laid [an egg] on the beach." It's also correct to say that she ***lied*** on the beach, if she was telling a falsehood while on the beach. You have to provide more information than you currently have. What actual action is being described, and when did it occur?

Comment: The usage is changing because English is a living language. Being old I don't like "I was laid on the beach", "I was sat in my car" and so on because 'laid' and 'sat' used to be regarded solely as _transitive_ verbs so I think "I laid what on the beach?" and "Who sat me in my car". However modern conversational usage accepts both 'sat' and 'laid' as _intransitive_ verbs. Grammarly is reflecting the newer usage but Word Power is not. Personally I prefer Word Power in this instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first sentence is correct: your second is incorrect.

Lay and Lie are two different verbs. In everyday spoken English they regularly get mixed up, perhaps because both may be followed by the word **on**, and because - annoyingly - the past tense of lie is lay.

**Lay** is a transitive verb. That means it takes a direct object.

```
I go in and lay the papers on the desk.
He is laying the table for dinner.
She laid it yesterday.  
When he had laid the table he left.
```

**Lie** is an intransitive verb. It doesn't take a direct object. It is like *yawn*. You don't yawn anything and you don't lie anything.

```
I lie on the bed, reading.
She was lying on the lawn.
She lay there all day.
When he had lain there for an hour he got up.
```

Comment: So why is one right and the other wrong, in OP's example sentence?

Comment: @Hot Licks Because it's the wrong verb. It should be (the past tense of) the verb **to lie**, not the (past tense of) the verb **to lay**. The verb 'to lay' has 'laid' as its past tense, and it always takes a direct object. She laid WHAT on the beach? An egg? (Hmm. Actually that is possible. She might be a hen. I don't know the context!) Did YOU give me the -1 btw?

Comment: So you're saying that "lay" is wrong??  The first sentence is INcorrect??

Comment: No! As I said in my answer, "the past tense of lie is lay."  I lie on my bed. Yesterday too I lay on my bed.

Comment: This answer is correct and the OP's second sentence is a mistake. She lay on the beach while etc. Simple past.But, the present perfect is **lain**. She has lain on the damn beach all day. The past perfect is also lain: He had lain there for two hours when his friends showed up. This answer **should not be downvoted**!

Comment: People are clueless.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks, Lambie :-)

Comment: But when was she on the beach?

Comment: She laid a towel on the beach, and lay down on it.

Comment: @Hot Licks Yesterday, OK? It was a hot day. She lay on the beach. Her kid played in the water. The thing with the shark happened. She drove home. She took a shower. That's when she realized! She'd left the goddam towel on the beach.

Comment: I think you have a bright future ahead of you in the grand old comic tradition of your fair isles ("the thing with the shark happened")

Comment: @Lambie: Spooky. Mostly *behind* me. *Fleetingly* bright perhaps.